# Adding JButtons from a array to a GridLayout in a for cycle

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

```
public class Nono extends JPanel implements ActionListener{


JButton[][] foo= new JButton[6][6];
JButton test;

public Nono(){
    TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Tablero de Juego");
    border.setTitleColor(Color.BLUE);
    setBorder(border);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(7,7));

    for( int i=0;i==6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j==6;j++){  
            foo[i][j]= new JButton("");
        }       
    }

    for( int i=0;i==6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j==6;j++){  
            add(foo[i][j]);             

        }   
    }
```

}

I've tried to add the buttons, but it does not work. I've added a test button to the same panel manually and that one does work. I've creating and adding it in the same 2 for cycles and in separate one for the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loops, I think you mean for your condition statements to be `i<6` rather than `i==6`

Example:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<6; j++){
```

Also your `GridLayout` should be 6x6 instead of 7x7:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(6,6));
```